# Isracoin: What hashrate should I be getting with intel core i5?

Tags: altcoin, mining-hardware, hashpower, cpu-mining

I'm only getting 13 kh/s using minerd with intel i5 and the lowfeemining.org pool. Shouldn't I be getting a better hashrate?[image]

Comment: BTW I realize CPU mining like this is not competitive. Just trying it out.

Comment: SHA-256 and scrypt mining are completely different. Isracoin is based on scrypt. What are you comparing your hashrate to?

Comment: I tried quark first and was getting closer to 200 kh/s.

Comment: You can't compare numbers like that.

Comment: That's what I figured. I don't really have anything to compare to. That's why I asked here.

Comment: This number seems right to me based on my limited knowledge. However, you should know that Isracoin is a fork of the more popular Dogecoin and AFAIK uses the same hash function, so you might have better luck asking about that. (And, I also believe Dogecoinn uses the same hash function as the even more popular Litecoin).

Comment: "i5" is a very big family. Exactly what processor, speed, and number of cores are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that IsraCoin uses the Scrypt-Hashing algorithm as suggested in the comments on the question, I found this [hardware overview table on Litecoin](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison#Intel) (which also uses Scrypt).

The table lists a number of `Intel Core i5` processors ranging in hashrate from **12 to 55 kHash/s**.
I.e. depending on what processor you have exactly and whether IsraCoin uses the same hashing scheme as LiteCoin, it is within the expected performance.

Comment: That's another good point you've raised - "Intel core i5" is not a processor model, it's a brand that spans 4 generations and several performance brackets in each. It's impossible to answer the original question without knowing the particular model.

Answer (score 0):

Hash Rate for any coin depends on these parameters like

1. Coin Algorithm (Scrypt/SHA256d/x11)
2. Fork Coin ( Like forked from
3. litecoin/bitcoin) Coin is CPU/GPU based mining
4. Better Stratum Connection b/w your hardware(system) and Mining Pool
5. Network Bandwidth.